# Why is Dictionary.ContainsKey() & ToString() causing GC Alloc?

Tags: c#, dictionary, garbage-collection, overriding, tostring

There's not much more I have to offer in terms of details other than the fact that there's around 1k instances that are running their own `ContainsKey()` and `ToString()` pretty often.

Location is just my personal replacement for Unity's `Vector3` to fit my needs:

```
[Serializable] public struct Location
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;
    public double Z;

    public Location(double x, double y, double z) : this()
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", X, Y, Z);
    }
}
```

(I know I'm breaking a rule of some sort with `Structs`.. just not sure how to achieve my needs another way atm.)

Here's a screenshot of the Profiler running:

[image: Unity_Profiler_ToString_ContainsKey_GC_Alloc]

As you can see, for most of the timeline, it's stable, then all of the sudden after my instances reach around 1k(quantity), (they start around 100-250) the CPU and Memory go wild due to what seems to be the GC allocations. I've been going through looking for what I can clean up a bit better, but all I see that's even causing ANY GC alloc is when I am running an:

```
if (_dictionary.ContainsKey(key)) {...}
```

and when renaming Unity GameObjects with:

```
part.name = "Part: " + part.Location.ToString();
```

If it just pertains to the unavoidable time it takes for the lookup, then are there any alternatives to `Dictionaries` that tend to function even slower but causing less GC alloc, and is there a more effective way to `override` the `ToString()` method?

***Addition:*** My Dictionary is Key: (my personal struct) Location, Value: Class instance.

Comment: It shouldn't be a surprise that `ToString()` needs to allocate memory - it's creating a string! You're then creating *another* string using string concatenation, so that statement creates two strings. We can't tell much about the dictionary lookup as you haven't shown us the type of it. (Maybe it's a key type that has an inefficient `GetHashCode()` or `Equals` method?)

Comment: My Dictionary is Key: (my personal struct) Location, Value: Class instance. (also added that info to the main post.)

Comment: @DaisyShipton I'm reading here: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1341
As you've given me SOME more direction than I previously had. Lol any additional input?

Comment: It's possibly that it's boxing because you haven't overridden `GetHashCode` or `Equals`. I would also implement `IEquatable<Location>` so that it doesn't need to box for the argument of `Equals` too. (At the moment I believe it *will* have to box to check `Equals`, so it may not need to allocate if there are no matching hash codes, but will otherwise.)

Comment: Alright, I'll take a look into that and report back. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning comments into an answer...

Your `ToString()` method is always going to create a new string, so that's no surprise. However, you're also using string concatenation, so you're creating *two* new strings. You could reduce this to one by just inlining the `ToString()` method. For example, using C# 6 interpolated strings for brevity:

```
var location = part.Location;
part.name = $"Part: {location.X}, {location.Y}, {location.Z}";
```

For the dictionary aspect, there are two issues:

- You're not overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, which *may* mean that the value is being boxed in order to call the implementations in `ValueType`. I'm not 100% sure on this; the rules on boxing can be complicated.
- You're not implementing `IEquatable<T>`, so it's *very* likely that any `Equals` calls will be boxing.

You can fix both of these easily:

```
[Serializable] public struct Location : IEquatable<Location>
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;
    public double Z;

    public Location(double x, double y, double z) : this()
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"{X}, {Y}, {Z}";

    public override bool Equals(object obj) =>
        obj is Location loc && Equals(loc);

    public bool Equals(Location other) =>
        X == other.X && Y == other.Y && Z == other.Z;

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // Replace with whatever implementation you want
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 23 + X.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + Y.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + Z.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    };
}
```

(That's using C# 7 syntax, but I'd expect that to still be okay if you're using a modern version of Unity with VS2017. If you're using an older version, you should be able to implement the same methods just in a slightly more longwinded fashion.)